# How to unit test didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, uiwindow

I am following the book "Test-Driven iOS Development" by Graham Lee and came across this section that isn't well explained at all.  The idea is not to instantiate `UIWindow` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but rather using an IBOutlet and hook it to an `UIWindow` xib file.  I can't get that working and can't find any example on the internet.

```
-(void)testWindowHasRootNavigationControllerAfterApplicationLaunch
{
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(window.rootViewController, navigationController, @"App delegate's navigation controller should be the root VC");
}

@implementation iTagNewsAppDelegateTests
{
    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}

- (void)setUp {
    window = [UIWindow new];
    navigationController = [UINavigationController new];
    appDelegate = [AppDelegate new];
    appDelegate.window = window;
    appDelegate.navigationController = navigationController;
}
```

**Code:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
BrowseOverflowViewController *firstViewController =
[[BrowseOverflowViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
    TopicTableDataSource *dataSource = [[TopicTableDataSource alloc]
        init];
    [dataSource setTopics: [self topics]];
    firstViewController.dataSource = dataSource;
    self.navigationController.viewControllers =
        [NSArray arrayWithObject: firstViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@interface BrowseOverflowAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@end
```

His full project is on [GitHub.](https://github.com/iamleeg/BrowseOverflow)
Is there any tutorial how to define a custom `UIWindow`? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read that book but found that I was able to test a full instance of my AppDelegate. Adapting it to your code:

```
- (void) setUp {
    //Could also use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] but I'm worried state may persist
    iTagNewsAppDelegate* appDelegate = [[iTagNewsAppDelegate alloc] init]
    [appDelegate application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:nil]; //Couldn't find a better option than sharedApplication here, fine if application param isn't used?
    //the rest of your setup here
}
```

This works in my project but I'm not sure about the side effects of using sharedApplication. You want a unit test to have a known beginning state and reusing the running app throughout your tests is usually a bad thing.